# Python server only receives one character from Java client?

Tags: java, python, macos, tcp, client-server

I'm trying to implement a simple Python server to communicate with some simple Java client code, but I'm getting some strange behavior.  I'm running Mac OSX 10.7.2.

Client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class JavaClient {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        String sentence;
        String modifiedSentence;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine() + '\n';
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence);
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Server code:

```py
import SocketServer

class PythonServer(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

Strangely, the first time I instantiate the server and send a request from the Java client, everything behaves as expected:

Java console:

```
test

FROM SERVER: TEST
```

Command line:

```
127.0.0.1 wrote:
test
```

But subsequent requests result in:

Java console:

```
test

FROM SERVER: T
```

Command line:

```
127.0.0.1 wrote:
t
```

So it looks like my server is only receiving the first character of my message, despite the fact that my client believes that it's sending the whole message.

To further complicate things, I created a Java server and Python client and the Java client / server combo and Python client / server combo don't have this problem, but the Python client / Java server does.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to `flush` your `outToServer` after writing the data that needs to go out to the server

Comment: @GETah I added a line to flush the buffer after writing to it, but this didn't change the behavior.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the [Nagle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) on the client before passing the socket to `DataOutputStream`:

```
clientSocket.noTcpDelay(true);
```

This is somewhat wasteful regarding network bandwidth but we can address that as well if that would be a problem for you.

There is also another potential problem, this time in your server code, which amounts to a duplicate
of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708835/receving-socket-python).

Comment: Enabling / disabling the Nagle algorithm doesn't seem to effect my output, but your second link fixed the problem - thank you!